# Why Anaconda has two same `libpython2.7.so`?

Tags: python, anaconda

There two identical `libpython2.7.so` in Anaconda's install directory. They are absolutely same(compared with `diff`).

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 19  Mar 23 20:20 /opt/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so -> libpython2.7.so.1.0
>   lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 19  Aug 22  2014 /opt/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.8-1/lib/libpython2.7.so -> libpython2.7.so.1.0

That makes me confused. Should I put the `/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.8-1/lib` directory in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the seemly more right one `/anaconda/lib`.

Why the anaconda guys put two identical python dynamic library in the package at different places? What're the purposes of the two directories?

Comment: Both of those are symbolic links.

Comment: Yeah, but both link to the file in their corresponding folder.@ColonelThirtyTwo

Comment: You don't specify where they point to. I wouldn't be surprised if they pointed to another symbolic link, which then points to the same `libpython2.7` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pkgs directory is the cache of packages used by conda. You shouldn't use those libraries directly.  Conda installs the packages to the install environment (in this case, `/opt/anaconda`) by hardlinking the files from `pkgs`.

Also, it is typically not necessary to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when using Anaconda. If you are using the Anaconda Python, it will load the `libpython2.7.so` from the Anaconda lib directory automatically.